# evaluate trigonometric

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

To all the genius out there , here is a question about expresssing summation of hyperboilc functions :

First of all, I've already proved that:

$$\sinh(x + 1)- \sinh(x) = (-1 + \cosh (1)) \sinh(x) + \sinh (1) \cosh(x)$$

$$\cosh(x + 1)- \cosh(x) = (-1 + \cosh (1)) \cosh(x) + \sinh (1) \sinh(x)$$

The later question asked me to use these results and  express the following sums:

$C_n = \cosh (0) + \cosh (1) + \cosh (2) + \ldots +\cosh (n)$

$S_n = \sinh (0) + \sinh (1) + \sinh (2) + \ldots+\sinh (n)$

I have learned a few summation of hyberbolic function by myself, please guide me through this new challenge , thank you .

Comment: Using the first two equations, you can rewrite $\cosh(x)$, $\sinh(x)$ into the form

$$\begin{align}
\cosh x &= ( A \cosh(x+1) + B\sinh(x+1) ) - (A \cosh(x) + B\sinh(x))\\
\sinh x &= ( C \cosh(x+1) + D\sinh(x+1) ) - (C \cosh(x) + D\sinh(x))\\
\end{align}
$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are constants to be determined. Once you do that, you can turn the sums $C_n, S_n$ into telescoping sums and read off the final answers.

Comment: ok let me try , Im still new to telescoping sums, just kinda know the idea of doing it .

Comment: @achillehui , Im sorry to ask how to you rewrite the equation coshx into as shown by you ? I've tried many times but still could not get it . Do you combine both the equation ? or just simply moving their position and factorize ?

Comment: Just combine the two equations. e.g. To get an expression for $\cosh x$, you multiply the $1^{st}$ equation by $\sinh 1$, the $2^{nd}$ equation by $1 + \cosh 1$, subtract them to cancel out the $\sinh x$ term...

Comment: ok thx , you are the best :D

Comment: @achillehui , sigh Im so sorry to bother u again, I still stuck at the rewriting step , I did as you said :

Comment: the equations I got is :                                                                                          **sinh 1 sinh x + sinh 1 sinh 1 -sinh 1 sinh x = - sinh 1 sinh x + sinh 1 sinh x cosh 1 + cosh x sinh 1 sinh 1**-------and--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**cosh x cosh 1 + cosh 1 cosh 1  + cosh x cosh 1 = - cosh 1 cosh x - cosh x + cosh 1 cosh 1 cosh x + cosh 1 cosh x + cosh 1 sinh 1 sinh x + sinh 1 sinh x**

Comment: what I don't under stand is how am I going to subtract the LHS   , since the **1st** equation consist of **sinh** and **2nd** consist of **cosh** . please bare with me , im struggling to do this .
( sorry for the messiness Im not used to use this website )

Comment: @achillehui , can u show me the complete method to solve fo Cn then I do Sn myself ? Its fine though if you are too busy .

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity of derivation, let $c = \cosh 1$ and $s = \sinh 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sinh(x+1) - \sinh x &= (c - 1) \sinh x + s \cosh x \tag{*1a}\\
\cosh(x+1) - \cosh x &= (c - 1) \cosh x + s \sinh x \tag{*1b}
\end{align}$$
$s \times (*1a) - (c-1) \times (*1b) \implies$
$$
\begin{align}
  & s \text{LHS}(*1a) - (c-1)\text{LHS}(*1b)\\ 
=\; & s\left( (c - 1) \sinh x + s \cosh x \right)
-(c-1)\left( (c - 1) \cosh x + s \sinh x \right)\\
=\; & (s^2 -(c-1)^2)\cosh x\\
=\; & 2(c-1)\cosh x
\end{align}
$$
This leads to
$$\cosh x = \frac12 \left(\frac{s}{c-1}\text{LHS}(*1a) - \text{LHS}(*1b)\right)
= A(x+1) - A(x)$$
where
$$A(x) = \frac12 \left(\frac{s}{c-1}\sinh x - \cosh x\right)$$
From this, we can conclude

$$\begin{align}
C_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \cosh k 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n ( A(k+1) - A(k) ) = A(n+1) - A(0)\\
&= \frac12 \left(\frac{\sinh(1)}{\cosh(1)-1}\sinh(n+1) - (\cosh(n+1) - 1 )\right)  
\end{align}
$$

The derivation of $S_n$ is similar, I will skip it here.

Comment: thx again, and sorry for the trouble , your help is apprieciated .